# In Android with Opencv, CvCameraViewListener2 class, Display orientation is portrait mode is anything Possible to camera view in Fullscreen

Tags: android, opencv

In opencv android, i change display orientation in portrait mode. Camera view is rotated. so i change the code

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();
        Core.transpose(mRgba, mRgbaT);
        Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaF, mRgbaF.size(), 0,0, 0);
        Core.flip(mRgbaF, mRgba, 0);
}
```

above code change to Portrait mode correct view. But camera view is middle of the screen. i need to change full screen view. Is anything possible to change full screen mode in portrait.[image].

Answer (score 0):

use mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Answer (score 0):

You can call a setRequestedOrientation with the desired orientation on your onCreate() method :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```